# List index out of range? (Python)

Tags: python, arrays, list

I have an array that has lists as it's entries( for examply, array= ([1,2],[2,3],[3,4]) ), and I want to loop through these lists and compare a specific item to see if it matches a criteria, but I keep getting this error: "Indexerror: list index is out of range"

this is my code:

```
for i in enumerate(arr):
        if arr([i][6]) == 0.0:
            humans= humans+[arr[i,col]]
```

I have checked the actual array by printing out array[1][6] for example, and I know for a fact that there's a value there. So why won't it loop through ?

Comment: if you type

    for i in enumerate(arr):

`i` is the tuple `(index,value)`. Can you post the stacktrace?

Comment: what do you know about `arr[i,col]`? How sure are you about the values of `i` and `col`? Rest assured that if python is telling you a list index is out of range, then it is.

Comment: `arr([i][6])`. You're calling `arr` with the 7th element of `[i]`, which is a single element list.

Comment: The error appears at the second line, the 3rd line seems fine, but I will double check right now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your understanding of `enumerate()` is wrong. It returns the list of tuples with each item mapped to its index. Here is the value it returned in your case:

```
>>> list(enumerate(arr))
[(0, [1, 2]), (1, [2, 3]), (2, [3, 4])]
```

If want to iterate so that `i` will have value from 0 to length of `arr`, you need to use `range()` as:

```
for i in range(len(arr))
```

Also the content of your list is :

```
arr = [[1,2],[2,3],[3,4]]
```

It is a 3X2 list, and you are doing `arr[i][6]`, it will give IndexError as length of each sub-list is just two

Comment: I just tried this, I still get the same error at the second line

Comment: @Sam: Check my edit